# Is it possible to execute a function at IIS for authentication before hits URLs?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-applications

Our applications are hosted at IIS as below hierarchy:

```
MainAppn1
---subAppn1
---subAppn2
---subAppn3
```

Is it possible to execute a function automatically at IIS to do authentication commonly for all sub applications whenever user hits url (for eg. http://server1/MainAppn1/subAppn1.aspx. Best answers would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: In ASP.NET, You could place code inside `Application_BeginRequest` . In ASP.NET Core, you could create a middle-ware.

Comment: We use asp.net webform 4.0. are there any possiblity to place executable authorization code (in the form of dll or httpmodule for intercepting request for preprocessing) to check every time page access before calling any sub applications such as subAppn1,subAppn2,subAppn3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement [Custom HTTP Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx).

```
namespace AspNetWebForm
{
    public class CustomHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
            application.AuthenticateRequest += Application_AuthenticateRequest;
            application.AuthorizeRequest += Application_AuthorizeRequest;
        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### web.config

Registering the HTTP Module in IIS 7.0 Integrated Mode.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="CustomHttpModule" type="AspNetWebForm.CustomHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Should I create this httpmodule class in a class library? if yes, then should I deploy a dll file in the Main folder MainAppn1.?. Please provide steps to place this common httpmodule authentication at IIS?

Comment: `Should I create this httpmodule class in a class library?` It is up to you.  Registering your custom HTTP Module in `web.config` is enough. You don't have to do anything in IIS.

Comment: "You don't have to do anything in IIS", unless `modules` section is loose enough to be overridden in `web.config` (but it is not always the case).

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Kindly answer to the following queries.. (1) how to deploy this custom httpModule as common one for all asp.net applications? (2) In which web.config file, I am supposed to configure either subAppn1 or subAppn2 or subAppn3 ?

Comment: @Muruga 1) You could create a separate project and either reference the same DLL file in all projects or create a nuget package. 2) Just place the registration in the application's web.config file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :). is it possible to intercept requests to authenticate using httpModule project at IIS without referring its dll file and configuring at web.config file in the existing production deployed subAppn1, subAppn2, subAppn3?

Comment: @Muruga No, it is not possible in ASP.NET Web Form. You need to inherit `IHttpModule` especially for authentication.

Comment: Thank you for great responses. If I am administrator, I will provide you a gold badge :)